Taking the right of others
A person is in 2nd grade of high school and remember that she cheated on some schoolwork and on some test (but not all) in elementary school and gets in to a high school that everyone can't because it depends on the grades from elementary school. Is she taking the rights of others  that didn't make it in to that high school, since she didn't deserve since she cheated?

Let's see the FATWAS-
[https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/279129]

Shaykh Ibn Baz (may Allah have mercy on him) was asked: A man got a job on the basis of a degree certificate, but he cheated in the exams for this degree. Now he is performing well, according to the testimony of his bosses. What is the ruling on his salary – is it permissible or prohibited?


He replied:“There is nothing wrong with it, in Sha’ Allah, but he must repent to Allah for what he did of cheating . That is provided that he is doing his work as it should be done. In that case, there is no problem with regard to his salary , but he erred by cheating in the past, and he must repent to Allah from that." (Majmu` Fatawa Ibn Baz  19/31)

This fatwa is more harsh but maybe true-
https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/299765
